# android menu submenu | list sublist

Tags: android, listview, menu, android-xml

I want a design like below
I don't know what to use either menu or list or else...)

[Here the First Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5dgA.png)

And if I clicked on one of the items it should show me another sub menu/list like below image

[I want to that type design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WBKN.png)

I am new to android and I want your help. Please help me here. Thanks.

Comment: you should try this link:~ https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/ its expandable list view so you can better idea

Comment: thanks. It helped a lot @HarshitTrivedi

Comment: upvote to comment @MrG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this you will get your result.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45942661/viewpager-is-expanding-under-the-navigationbar-in-case-of-coordinatorlayout-and -------- can you help me here also?